# Copy N-D array in C++ using memcpy

Tags: c++, memcpy

I have a 4-D static array

```
#define MAX_NUM 64
unsigned char Stamps[MAX_NUM][16][16][3];
```

where each row (i.e., `Stamps[MAX_NUM][][][]`) represents RGB patch cropped from an image

How can I use `memcpy` to copy one row from `Stamps`to a dynamic array:

`unsigned char *DynArr = new unsigned char [16 * 16 * 3];`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca This dupe is pretty poorly written, and I think (can't even clearly understand the question, even with those answers... ) that it relates to a more complex question. Here a single `std::memcpy` would be sufficient.

Comment: @Holt I posted two different links. If you mean the first, yeah, I agree. The second one (the one I actually marked as duplicate) seems more clear.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I was refering to the second one actually. This is about copying "something" from a `int[100][100]` to a `int[10][10]`. I can't even understand if it's about copying a row and then reshaping it to a 10x10, or if it's about copying a submatrix... This question is much simpler since it's basically copying a row of `Stamps` and flattening it... And since the layout is contiguous, it's basically `std::memcpy(DynArr, Stamps[istamp], sizeof *Stamps);`.

Comment: @Holt I completely misread the linked duplicate. Removing both links.

Comment: Btw, the copy can also be a 3D array: `unsigned char (*DynArr)[16][3] = new unsigned char[16][16][3];` This works as long as the sizes of the inner dimensions are compile time constants (`16` and `3`), the outer dimension size (here also `16`) can be supplied at runtime and is omitted from the type of `DynArr`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
std::memcpy(DynArr, Stamps[row], sizeof Stamps[row]);
```

Comment: I would probably still use `&Stamps[row]` for the source, even though array decay results in the same pointer value...

Comment: @jxh If personally find `&Stamps[row]` very misleading, maybe `&Stamps[row][0]`.

Comment: If I had an array of `Foo`, then to copy a `Foo` into a `char [sizeof(Foo)]`, I would use `&array[i]`. In this case, `typedef char Foo[16][16][3];`.

Comment: @jxh yeah, I guess that's equally meaningful in my opinion. Doesn't matter much when the address is the same, and the pointer will be reinterpreted anyway.

Comment: @Holt: I explained my reasoning in a separate answer.

Comment: @jxh Again, it's opinion but, if you had a `Stamps a[16][16][3]` and wanted to copying it to a `Stamps b[16 * 16 * 3]`, you would probably do `std::memcpy(b, a, ...)`, or `std::memcpy(b, &a[0], ...)`, not `std::memcpy(b, &a, ...)`, so I think `&Stamps[row]` is pretty weird here.

Comment: @Holt: `std::memcpy(b, &a, sizeof(a))` is idiomatic for any `a`.

Comment: @jxh I don't agree for arrays, especially when you want to flatten then, I personally find that it makes the code harder to understand. It really depends if you see the array as an object of type "array" or as an array of elementary object :) But that's opinion, let's not continue that discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Just think of the problem as having an array of `Foo`.

```
#define MAX_NUM 64
Foo Stamps[MAX_NUM];
```

And now you want to copy a `Foo`.

```
unsigned char *DynArr = new unsigned char[sizeof(Foo)];
std::memcpy(DynArr, &Stamps[row], sizeof(Stamps[row]));
```

This would "work" for any type `Foo`. In your case, `Foo` is a 3-D array.

```
typedef unsigned char Foo[16][16][3];
```

[@eeroika's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611687/315052) works correctly, because when `Foo` is an array, an instance of it will decay to a value equal to the address of its first element. For arrays, the address of its first element is the same as the address of the array itself. However, if `Foo` were a non-array type, you would need to use the address-of operator.